# Does my From address need to exist for Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I own a domain - for the purpose of this question, let's call it example.com.

I have verified example.com with Amazon SES. I have set up the DKIM stuff as well. Everything is working; I have no problems sending outgoing emails, and I have already been granted production access.

The question: I am sending emails from no-reply@example.com, but this email address does not actually exist. Should I be worried about this? Is it bad to send emails from an email address that does not actually exist? Since I verified the domain, it seems that I can send emails from any email address I choose to invent.

(My emails are 'email validation' emails. We do not wish to capture any form of reply from our users, and bounces would only occur due to users registering fake email addresses - despite our warning that it is pointless to do so.)

I searched everywhere for an answer to this question, and I'm very surprised that I haven't found an explicitly clear answer to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is very common, with SES and/or any other batch mailing type service where you don't want any replies to the sending address - I don't see any problem.

Comment: I was afraid that Amazon SES would somehow need my address to be real to report bounces or something. Also, I was worried that receiving addresses may be able to check if the sending address existed or not, and then mark my emails as spam after realizing it does not, in fact, exist. But I guess everything is OK, thanks!